# Java in Processing: Make a circle go clockwise around the window endlessly

Tags: java, processing

My current code shows a circle that goes around the window once in a clockwise rotation, and then moves off the screen in the upper right corner when it's making its way around a second time. How can I edit my code, so the circle continues to go around the screen endlessly and never moves off the edge?

```
// cirlce radius
final int radius = 25; 
// circle x position 
int xPos = 15; 
int yPos = 15;
int xDir = 4; 
int yDir = 0;


void setup()
{
 size(500, 500); 
 background(177, 237, 247);
}

void draw()
{
  background(177, 237, 247); 
  ellipse(xPos, yPos, radius, radius); 
  
  xPos = xPos + xDir; 
  yPos = yPos + yDir;
  
  if (xPos > width - 15) { 
    yDir = 4;
    xDir = 0;
} if (yPos > height - 15) {
  xDir = -4; 
  yDir = 0;
} if (xPos < width - 485) {
  xDir = 0; 
  yDir = -4;
} if (yPos < height - 485) {
  yDir = 0; 
  xDir = 4;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you know of the `else` keyword? You need to make exactly one condition succeeds.

Comment: post a working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd and 4th argument of [`ellipse`](https://processing.org/reference/ellipse_.html) are the length of the axis, instead  of the length of the semi axis. Therefore you need to multiple the `radius` by 2.
When the ellipse reaches an edge, you need to limit the position of the ellipse by the edge:

```java
// cirlce radius
final int radius = 25; 
// circle x position 
int xPos = radius; 
int yPos = radius;
int xDir = 4; 
int yDir = 0;


void setup() {
   size(500, 500); 
   background(177, 237, 247);
}

void draw()
{
    background(177, 237, 247); 
    ellipse(xPos, yPos, radius*2, radius*2); 
    
    xPos = xPos + xDir; 
    yPos = yPos + yDir;
    
    if (xPos > width - radius) {
        xPos = width - radius;
        yDir = 4;
        xDir = 0;
    } 
    if (yPos > height - radius) {
        yPos = height - radius;
        xDir = -4; 
        yDir = 0;
    } 
    if (xPos < radius) {
        xPos = radius;
        xDir = 0; 
        yDir = -4;
    } 
    if (yPos < radius) {
        yPos = radius;
        yDir = 0; 
        xDir = 4;
    }
}
```

[image]